# Getting DISTINCT company info while normalizing data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm normalizing some data that I got in a flat file where company and contact info are mixed which look like this:

```
company_id | company_name | person_id | first_name | last_name | sic_code
123 | "Acme, Inc." | 111 | "John" | "Smith" | 54789
123 | "Acme, Inc." | 222 | "Jane" | "Doe" | 54789
234 | "Global, LLC" | 333 | "James" | "Brown" | 94574
```

So, I'd like my SQL statement to return unique company information that looks like this:

```
123 | "Acme, Inc." | 54789
234 | "Global, LLC" | 94574
```

I tried the following but I still get repeated data. For example, Acme, Inc. still comes up multiple times.

```
SELECT DISTINCT company_id, company_name, sic_code
FROM MyTable
ORDER By company_id
```

How do I get not just `DISTINCT` company ID's but extended data for all unique companies?

Comment: In this case it shouldn't, can you show an example of what you are getting? I am guessing that the "duplicates" you are getting is due to some sort of difference in the column values. So for example, there may be extra white space in one value, or perhaps the spelling is different. So you may want to do a trim on the columns first, or check for spelling differences.

Comment: For your provided sample data, you will get your requested output. So there is something unexplained here. How is the data imported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
select company_id, company_name, sic_code from (
    select 
      company_id,
      company_name,
      sic_code,
      row_number() over (partition by company_id order by company_id) rn
    from tbl
) t
where rn = 1
```